# $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) search is not working for few letters

Tags: jquery, search

I have worked on search items using $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) it is not working for few letters I don't know why. I have implemented the search on table td elements

my code:

```
<input id="button_id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">

$("#button_id").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#table_id td").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

**Updated**

Will the search works if I have div's inside table td? I have html like

```
<table class="" id="table_id">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
  <div class="row m-0">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" id="" pname="" value="947">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    product search item presents here  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

will it work if product div has price and channel details like below

```
<div class="col-md-7 myproduct_type1_div">
  <b>product search item presents here</b><br><b>0.75</b>                          
  <br>                                      
   1 Channel(s)                                             
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me why the search is not working on letters 'a,b,c,e,h,i,l,n,t'

Is there any other alternate way to achieve the search on 'table td' elements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;` inside the `filter` then use  `$("#table_id td").filter(....).toggle()` ..`.toggle()` after the `filter`

Comment: Tried that but it is not working, earlier working letters are also not working now after trying your solution.

Comment: toggle is not a good idea to do that .. I'll post an answer

Comment: @PrasadPatel I just tested your code, it's working fine, it works on `a` and show all the items because they all have a, but when you enter `b` as no one has b it doesn't show anything, it's working so well, what's the problem?

Comment: here you can check it: https://jsfiddle.net/yhx2eb7n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I assumed you want to `hide/show` the rows which holds the `<td>` matches the input</sup>

- Using `.toggle` is not a good idea to hide/show elements in filter .. you need to use `.hide()` , `.show()` or something similar
- You need to `hide` the rows first before go to filter
- To select the parent row use `.closest()`;

```js
$("#button_id").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#table_id tr").hide().find("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
  }).closest('tr').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="button_id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">

<table id="table_id">
<tr>
  <td>Any thing Here</td>
  <td>Another thing row 1</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>Any thing Here row 2</td>
  <td>Another thing</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>Any thing Here</td>
  <td>Another thing row 3</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

If you still wants to `hide/show` the **td's**

```js
$("#button_id").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#table_id td").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.col-md-7').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
  }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="button_id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..">

<table class="" id="table_id">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" id="" pname="" value="947">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          product 1 here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" id="" pname="" value="947">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          product 2 here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="" name="" id="" pname="" value="947">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          product 3 here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  <tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have checked your code snippet, it is not working properly. I have searched for letters w and o it is showing all the items. Also when I search with numbers 3, 2 and 1 that entire table row it is showing. I think it is showing that total row of matched item.

Comment: Your code snippet is working fine but when I use your code for my requirement it is not working. I have div's inside table td's will it work like that if I have div's. please check my updated question.

Comment: plus 1 for your efforts, but it is not working for me, please check my updated question.

Comment: @PrasadPatel If the divs holds the product search has the same `col-md-7` class you can use `.find('.col-md-7')` you can take a look at updated second snippet

Comment: Still it is not working, my product div not only has product name but also few other data like price and channel name. will it work if product div has price and channel name like I updated in my question.

Comment: @PrasadPatel The simple thing is use `console.log($(this).text())` inside `.filter` or inside `.each()` and see what you'll get

Comment: You're totally welcome @PrasadPatel .. Have a great day :-)